# Schema to store/generate dynamic messages with placeholder

Tags: sql-server, database, schema

I am creating an application to display the notification like facebook. I have database schema to save the user-specific notification. The notification message contains the placeholders. E.g. Suppose we have below notification messages (Calling it **Notification Template**):

1. {FrinedName} like your photo.
2. {FriendName} like your page {PageName}.
3. {FrinedName} posted a message in {groupName}.
4. It's {friendName} birthday today.
5. {FriendName} and {#count} likes your photo

So here the text inside {} represents placeholder and the value of these placeholders need to be replaced at the runtime. 
Now I want to keep these placeholders and their value source in database tables. 
The Value of different placeholders may refer to the different columns in different tables. (E.g. the value of **{FriendName}** may belong to the **User** tables **LoginName** column, value of **{PageName}** will refer to **Pages** table's **Name** column and the value of **{groupname}** placeholder refer to the the **Groups** tables **Name** column).

So, I would like to get the data dynamically for the placeholders. What is the best way to store such type of data in the database (something like below).

1. **dbo.NotificationTemplates** - Table to store all the notification templates
2. **dbo.TemplatePlaceholders** - Table to store the placeholders in the template
3. **dbo.TemplatePlaceholdersMapping** - Table to store the mapping of placeholders in a template.
4. **dbo.PlaceholderValueProvider** - table to store the placeholder's value source, i.e. from where to get the value for placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use scalar function, you can have multiple conditions in scalar function and at the end, return your result in one column